# Proving $aI+A$ is Positive Definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, positive-definite

> Let $A \in M_{n \times n}^\Bbb C$ be a **self adjoint** matrix. Prove that there is $a \in \Bbb R$ such that $aI+A$ is  a positive definite matrix.

**What I did so far**

Let $v$ be a vector in an **orthonormal basis** of $A$ which exists since $A$ is self adjoint.$A$ is also diagonalizable so $Av=\lambda v$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. I now use the definition of the inner product:

$$\langle(aI+A)v,v\rangle=\langle(av+Av),v\rangle=\langle a v,v\rangle+\langle Av,v\rangle=a\langle v,v\rangle+\lambda\langle v,v\rangle$$.

Now I think I have to prove that this term is bigger than $0$. $<v,v> $ is bigger from the inner product definition, but how do I deal with this scalar $a$? can I just say that it's positive since I have to prove there is a positive one?

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: You need to choose an $a$ that is big enough, or convince the reader that such a choice exists.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom is there a reason there wouldn't be one? They tell me $a$ is some real number. Why can't I choose an arbitrary real number which is positive?

Comment: Well, it needs to be big enough and positve.  For example, what if $A = -I$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I see. Do you think the way I moved through the problem was good? Do you know how to continue from here?

Answer (score 1):

Another (perhaps simpler) approach is to work with eigenvalues.

First, $A$ has real eigenvalues. Second, if $\lambda_i$ is an eigenvalue
of $A$, then the corresponding eigenvalue of $B=A+aI$ is $\lambda_i +a$.
Third, a  self adjoint matrix is positive definite iff the eigenvalues are positive.

Putting all together, by picking any $a > \min(\lambda_i) $ ,  $B=A+aI$ results positive definite.